# Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component> from render

Tags: reactjs

```
<script type="text/babel">
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

    const Element = (firstName, lastName) => {
        <div>
            Hello, {firstName} {lastName}
        </div>;
    };

    <Element firstName="John" lastName="Doe" />;

    ReactDOM.render(Element, rootElement);
</script>
```

Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing {} in "firstName, lastName" and return the div

```js
<script type="text/babel">
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

    const Element = ({firstName, lastName}) => (
        <div>
            Hello, {firstName} {lastName}
        </div>;
    );

    ReactDOM.render(<Element firstName="John" lastName="Doe" />, rootElement);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First - If you use curly braces `{}` with `arrow function` in you `Element` component, you need to use `return` keyword. Or, use first bracket `()` instead of curly braces.

Second - you needn't write this line `<Element firstName="John" lastName="Doe" />`, instead write this line inside `ReactDOM.render`. Or, store this in a variable and pass it inside `ReactDOM.render`.

```
<script type="text/babel">
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

    const Element = (firstName, lastName) => (
        <div>
            Hello, {firstName} {lastName}
        </div>;
    );

    ReactDOM.render(<Element firstName="John" lastName="Doe" />, rootElement);
</script>
```